# Oracle 12c RAC : How to check the load balancing status

Tags: oracle

With multiple SCAN VIP, we’d like to check if DB sessions are sure to be balanced or not.
I’d be so grateful if you give me any useful commands.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use this simple query:

```
select inst_id, count(*) from gv$session group by inst_id;
```

It will return the number of sessions per instance.

To narrow your results you can also add some where conditions, like:

`where username is not null` or `where type not like 'BACKGROUND'`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @user2948956 ! So we can get to know db sessions are balancing at each instance. We’ll try to use it with gv$instance and gv$process. It will help us lot :)

Comment: @Sachiko If this is what you were looking for, i kindly ask you to vote mine as the answer to your question, so other users with the same question, could find the correct answer quicker.

Comment: ‘@EdwardKirk, you’re right! Let me vote it when my reputation will be over 15 ( With my new question I’ll get other 5 reputations before long) Thanks for another precious advice:)

Comment: Oh... forgot about the reputation system, btw i upvoted your comment, since the gv$process wasn’t in my answer and someone could find it helpful :) (it also gave you a little boost to your rep. :) )